# How should I handle many AJAX calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, client-side

I am trying to write a plugin which will work a lot with my server. Every page load will invoke an AJAX call to my server for data, the server should return a simple string.

Now I am trying to understand what would be the best aproach for this type of program.

Should I just create an AJAX call every time I need the data or is there some method I could create an open connection (despite the change of webpages) to save on server power?

Should I somehow listen to some port or something of the sort?

Do I have other options or what should I do to do this the most efficient way?

Comment: What is the purpose of the Ajax call?

Comment: The call will fetch a short string, which ofcourse will take time for the server to process.

Comment: If you give more info it will help us to give a better answer.  What is in the string?

Comment: I'm sorry for being rude but i'd rather not say, we're talking about a string not more then 200 chars which contains important data for the plugin.

Comment: If you're doing multiple AJAX calls at once, you should look into ways to consolidate them into as few calls as possible. JSON makes it possible to send large amounts of data in an organized object or array using a single AJAX call. If you're doing a single AJAX call over and over at regular intervals, you should look into making the data as simple and the server code as efficient as possible, and make sure you're not caching the URL.

Comment: I'm preforming 1 ajax call, but the plugin will be included in all of the webpages so every page load will invoke an ajax call, so i can't really consolidate less then that :) i also have no way of storing the data in local storage as every page should have new data.

Comment: I agree with Blazemonger. Consolidating multiple calls within a certain timeframe into a single pipeline is a way to go.

Comment: Does the result change every single time you call? What is the problem exactly? Are you trying to do premature optimization?

Comment: Yes i am because if it might be impossible to optimize this in which case i might drop the project. the result is changing each time ya. I'm mostly trying to understand what are my best options to intract with a server.

Comment: Does each page request a different string? or random string?

Comment: Since you say you have to perform one call on every page load, is there a reason you can't just include the data into the HTML (using PHP, ASP.net, or any other server-side technology)?

Comment: How many concurrent calls are you expecting? If you only have a few users at a time, having one single AJAX call per page load is not heavy on the server at all.

Comment: Each request has a different string and @Kitsune I can't because i don't know all the string at first time, each page has a new string i don't know before. and nico, i'm talking about alot of users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HTML5 **websockets** (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/)
If you use this approach, then you will need to re-think the way you program your webserver, since websockets don't follow the request-response paradigm AJAX do. Instead they use a connection to stream data so you will need to open a port on your server and listen to it, the way to do it depends on the language or framework you are using. This is fast and responsive but will only work on most modern browsers.

Other approach is using **Long Polling** (http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery). This is used by some chat clients. It works sending an AJAX request to the server, the server receives it and keeps it waiting until the data is available and then the response is sent. Then the client makes another request, waits and repeats.

Probably you will almost never want to send simple strings to the client. It's almost always better to use XML or JSON to encode the response.

Comment: My initial thought was using JSON, but since wer're talking about 1 full string i see no reason to add extra chars with json. The solutions you provided seems (to me) valid only for the same page, but i'm changing pages so wouldn't i have to open the socket again? and i can't understand how long polling can help me but this is the kind of information i'm looking for so i'll +1 it :)

Comment: If you use JSON instead, the overhead will be of some 10-20 (nothing to be worried about) extra chars and it's a better practice, it will be easier latter to add new features to your system without breaking the existing code, but you might never need it. If you are changing pages there is no way for you to keep any connection open (of any kind). You can embed a IFRAME on your page and use it to navigate while you use the base page to manage all the connection stuff.

Comment: You've convinced me about the JSON :) However, i know js is saved into memory as it's run, so are you telling me that when page reloads the browser (Chrome or FF) deletes all the data from it's memory? can i somehow order it to remember then and maybe then i'll be able to maintain a connection open

Comment: Long polling is useful when your page has to wait for some data and you want to display it as soon as it's available (e.g. a chat rooom, google chat uses this method). The server accepts your request but leaves you waiting until the data is ready to be sent and then it sends it and then closes the connection. In contrast, web sockets keep the connection open until either the client or the server (or a failure) closes the connection.

Comment: So if i'll create a socket with events, and on next page load can i check if socket is still open in memory and just bind the same events to it in order to not open new ones?

Comment: You can store data on SOME modern browsers using HTML5 local storage (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage), you can even create databases there, but there is no way to keep a connection open. You will need to either save the state of the page and re-open the connection on every page load OR avoid page-loads using AJAX or some other technique.

Comment: No, the page and all it's contents disappear completely when you navigate away from your current page. (there is nothing you can do about it, except maybe writing your own browser)

Comment: Well maybe i'll try, if people use IE mine can't be worse ;) Thanks though this answers my question! u should add a sum of this conversation to the answer i think to clarify that what i wanted is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a simple AJAX call and put it on each page, or save it as it's own file and put a server include on each page in the header. Simple as that!

```
$(document).load(function(){    

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/where_your_string_is.php",
        success: function(msg){

            $("#stringHolder").html(msg);

            }

    }); 

});
```

Comment: I'm writing a plugin and don't have access to the server. Your answer is exactly what i have so far, an ajax request per page and i'm looking for a better way to do that.

Comment: @eric.itzhak A better way? Using AJAX? Hmmmm...this is pretty easy.

Comment: I am looking for an alternative to ajax if that what is takes. i just need to create a session between a website and my server using JS, the problem is pages change so code re-executes. The way u provided is in fact easy but it's the regular way.

Comment: @eric.itzhak I take it you don't want the code to re-execute? That must mean the string doesnt change at all... Either way, your going to need 'something' on each if you are trying to access the string. Or you can pass the string in a cookie, or even in the url.

Comment: @eric.itzhak Could explain the order of events better, like the mechanics of what is supposed to happen when the user is browsing your site?

Comment: @eric.itzhak Why not use a server include for the string?

Comment: as i mentioned in the question i'm writing a plugin other people could use on their websites. My code will be included in all the web pages(like google analytics). Now each page should contact the server for a string but i'm intrested in somehow maintaing an open connection between the pages or something of the sort to somehow decrease the amount of processing my server will have to do.

Comment: @eric.itzhak Understood...It seems to me an "open connection" would put more load on your server than an AJAX call.  I may be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

Websockets API allows bi-directional communication, but I've just found that there's another option called [HTML SSE](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) that might be used if you only need to pull data. So if you've stumbled upon this question, consider this option as well.